# AttributeError on field defined in init

Tags: python

```
class Config(abc.ABC):
    def __init__(self, config_path: Union[str, PathLike]):
        with open(config_path, "w+") as file:
            self._config = yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.BaseLoader)
            user_defined_attrs = {k: v for k, v in self.__class__.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith("__")}
            for key in user_defined_attrs.keys():
                self.__dict__[key] = user_defined_attrs[key]
                self.__class__.__dict__[key] = self._config[key]

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        print("test")
        print(self._config)
        self.__dict__[name] = value
        print(yaml.dump(self._config))


class GeneralConfig(Config):
    test: int
    token: str


general_config = GeneralConfig(CONFIGS_PATH.joinpath("general_config.yaml"))
general_config.test = 5
```

This code is giving me an error `AttributeError: 'GeneralConfig' object has no attribute '_config'` when calling the `__setattr__` method. What am I doing wrong here? I have tried to change the name of the variable or overriding the init method in the subclass but there's no result.

Comment: It would be helpful to see some comments about what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Sounds like you want to make this a regular subclass instead of an abstract baseclass.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: The problem is that `Config.__setattr__` is called when you try to define `self._config`, so `self._config` *isn't* defined yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd be better off using a dict to dataclass constructor rather than setting attributes directly on the class like this. I'm a big fan of [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/), [dataclass-factory](https://pypi.org/project/dataclass-factory/), or [dataclasses-json](https://github.com/lidatong/dataclasses-json)

Example Yaml:

```
test: 1
token: test
```

Define a base class with a helper method to load the config from a file:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Type, TypeVar

from dataclass_factory import Factory
import yaml


FACTORY = Factory()
T = TypeVar("T")


@dataclass
class Config:
    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls: Type[T], config_path: str) -> T:
        with open(config_path, "r") as file:
            config = yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.BaseLoader)
        return FACTORY.load(config, cls)
```

Now you can define a config type like this:

```
@dataclass
class GeneralConfig(Config):
    test: int
    token: str


general_config = GeneralConfig.from_yaml("config.yaml")
print(general_config)
```

```
GeneralConfig(test=1, token='test')
```

Answer (score 0):

`__setattr__` is called unconditionally on *every* attempt to create or modify an attribute (unlike `__getattr__`, which is only called when the normal attribute lookup fails).

This means that the line

```
self._config = yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.BaseLoader)
```

is implemented using

```
self.__setattr__('_config', yaml.load(...))
```

and inside `__setattr__`, you try to access `self._config`, which you haven't actually created yet.

One workaround would be to actually set the attribute using `super().__setattr__`, *then* do whatever additional processing you want to do.

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    super().__setattr__(name, value)
    print("test")
    print(self._config)
    print(yaml.dump(self._config))
```